# Show 2 results by div

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I have the following foreach:

```
<?php 
foreach($result15 as $row15) { 
   $thumb15 = $row15->thumb;
   $id15 = $row15->id_discografia;
?>
<div class='wrapper'>
   <div class="album"><img src="img/<?php echo $thumb15; ?>" alt="" width="246" height="246"></div>
</div>  

<?php } ?>
```

But thus appears only a div .album within each div .wrapper. How do I see two divs .album within each div .wrapper?

**UPDATE**

Guys, found the solution:

```
<?php
$total = 0;
foreach($result15 as $row15){ 
$thumb15 = $row15->thumb;
$id15 = $row15->id_discografia;

if($total == 0){
    echo '<div class="wrapper">';
}        
?>
<div class="album" data-disco="disco<?php echo $id15; ?>">
     <img src="img/<?php echo $thumb15; ?>" alt="" width="246" height="246">
</div>
<?php
$total = $total + 1;

if($total % 2 == 0){
    echo '</div>';
    $total = 0;
}
}
 ?>
```

Comment: try using echo inside foreach loop

Comment: @blackuprise I beleive I need a counter. But I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='wrapper'>
   <div class="album"><img src="img/<?php echo $thumb15; ?>" alt="" width="246" height="246">
   <div class="album"><img src="img/..." alt="" width="246" height="246"></div>
</div>
```

Something like this?

**EDIT**

I dont understand what you want. But you can do this to get two divs, but you will need to get your image path for the second div image:

```
<?php 
foreach($result15 as $row15) { 
   $thumb15 = $row15->thumb;
   $id15 = $row15->id_discografia;

echo "<div class='wrapper'>";
echo '<div class="album"><img src="img/'.$thumb15.' alt="" width="246" height="246"></div>';
echo '<div class="album"><img src="img/'.$thumb15.' alt="" width="246" height="246"></div>';
echo '</div>';  
 } ?>
```

Comment: yeah! Something like this: a .wrapper for each two .album div

Comment: @user2433958 so just add what I have to your php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
foreach($result15 as $row15) { 
   $thumb15 = $row15->thumb;
   $id15 = $row15->id_discografia;

echo "<div class='wrapper'>";
echo '<div class="album"><img src="img/'.$id15 .' alt="" width="246" height="246"></div>';
echo '<div class="album"><img src="img/'.$id15 .' alt="" width="246" height="246"></div>';
echo '</div>';  
 } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution could be to use [array chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) considering you want to treat the data in 'chunks' of 2 images at a time. This way, if you want to alter how many images appear in a wrapper you only need to change your chunk size.

```
$chunkSize = 2;
foreach (array_chunk($result15, $chunkSize) as $wrapperImages) {
    echo '<div class="wrapper">';
    foreach ($wrapperImages as $image) {
        $thumb = $image->thumb;
        echo '<div class="album"><img src="img/'.$thumb.' alt="" width="246" height="246"></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```